# Inheritance problem while changing variable value C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

What I'm trying to do is to change a variable from `class A` inside  `class B` and make it the same in `class C`

```
class A
{
protected:
    string name = "A";
};

class B: public A
{
protected:
    string A::name="B";
};

class C: public B
{
 // here i want "name" to be "B"
};
```

But the problem is, i'm getting an error in `class C`  "illegal qualified name in member declaration".

Comment: Do you want to change `name` of class A inside class B?

Comment: No no, I just want to change varaible declared in `class A`, inside `class B` and make that variable appread in changed form inside `class C` @TonyTannous

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like this. If the field is being initialized in the base class, it is being initialized only in the base class. In other classes you can only change already initialized field.
One of the ways to do what you want can be passing the value in the constructor. So:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::string initName = "A") : name(std::move(initName)) {}
protected:
    string name;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B() : A("B") {}
};

class C: public B
{
// name will be "B" here
};
```

Comment: Knew about dealing with it by constructors, but had hope i can make it different way. Anyway, thanks for help

Comment: @Bartasus1 unfortunately there is no way to deal with it without constructors. The reason is that in C++ initialization of base class fields may happen only in the base class.

Comment: Done same thing, but just in a little bit different way. Maybe someone will find it easier to read : `B() { A::name = "B";}`

Comment: @Bartasus1 No, that's inefficient and everyone who's been programming C++ for some time would immediately change it back. You can't even do that for classes that can't be default constructed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo well, for my project it does the job pretty well, so i'll leave it

Comment: @Bartasus1 You will then be initializing `name` with one value and then overwrite it directly. It's code like that one usually wants to avoid. If you don't want `A` to have a constructor, why not give full access to `A`, like in `struct A { string name = "A"; };` You can then initialize it from `B` like this: `class B : public A { public: B() : A{"B"} {} };`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Those A,B,C classes are simplified classes from my project. `Class A` is "mother" class, `class B` is one of "fraction" classes, and `class C` represents certain characters. I want to make those characters contain name of fraction they belong to. I already did that, just by adding `A::name = " B " ; `  to the `class B` constructor

Comment: @Bartasus1 I'm not saying that it doesn't work. It's just that it's inefficient and that experienced C++ programmers would not do it like that. Are you using polymorphism? Will all instances of `A`, `B` and `C` have a static name? If so, just create a virtual member function in the base class that you can override: `virtual const std::string& name() const { static const std::string rv = "A"; return rv; }` This way all instances of `A` will share the same memory for the name and constructing an `A` will not instantiate a new `std::string` every time.

Comment: @Bartasus1 In `B` you simply `override` the function: `const std::string& name() const override { static const std::string rv = "B"; return rv; }` and if `C` is supposed to have the same name as `B`, don't override the function in `C`.

Comment: @Bartasus1 It became so ugly in the comments so I made an answer instead.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Why is this inefficient? This is just one line of code added to one constructor

Comment: @Bartasus1 Because you default construct the string first and then copy assign a value to it instead of copy constructing it directly. It's a minor difference but details matter sometimes - and some objects can't even be default constructed so it's better to "_do it right_" always. Also, if all the instances of a class share the same name what you do now will be _a lot_ more inefficient that my proposed version returning a static string. That string will only be instantiated _once_ no matter how many `A` s you create. One time for all `A`'a and one time for all `B`'s and `C`'s.

Comment: @Bartasus1 Btw, I looked at your other questions and it seems like you're creating some sort of game, correct? I assume you are using polymorphism so store misc. objects / monster / players already so the overhead of the dynamic dispatch I'm suggesting in my answer is (most probably) in your code already (or should probably be).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, you are correct. I'm creating a game and I use polymorphism, but for some different actions.I'm a bit too lazy to write all that code, just to change one variable. Oh,`A` has one object and there are a few `B` and many `C` objects as well.

Comment: @Bartasus1 "_I'm a bit too lazy_" - This will come back and bite you - promis :-) Anyway, if you want reflection (names of classes in runtime and decision manking based on it) I think you should study C++20. Rumour has it that reflection is added to the language. If that's the case, building a new game in 2020 with home-made reflection makes it old before it's even finished. Why the aversion against constructions etc.? They _do_ give you control.

Comment: "_constructions_" should be _constructors_. - writing on a phone ...

Comment: @Bartasus1 Did you fint any way to do it without constructors or initializors of sorts?

Comment: @TedLyngmo wdym ?

Comment: @Bartasus1 I mean, since you haven't accepted any of the answers given, did you find an alternative solution?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I sticked with my option. It does the job and I'm not especially interested in making my game as efficient as possible. At least for now

Answer (score 0):

what you want is to initialize the value of your variable in the constructor

```
public class B: public A
{
public:
    B():name{"B"}{};
}
```

Comment: So there is no way i could make it without constructors?

Comment: @Bartasus1 Yes there is. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the classes are static and you don't mind using polymorphism, you could add a `virtual` member function returning the name of the class. Simply `override` the function in the derived classes to return a different name.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual const std::string& name() const {
        static const std::string rv = "A";
        return rv;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    const std::string& name() const override {
        static const std::string rv = "B";
        return rv;
    }
};

class C: public B {
    // doesn't override name() - will be named "B"
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> objs;     // Storage of base class pointers.

    objs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<A>()); // Add pointers to...
    objs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<B>()); // objects of different...
    objs.emplace_back(std::make_unique<C>()); // derived classes.

    // call the virtual member function through the base class pointer
    for(auto& uptr : objs) {
        std::cout << uptr->name() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output

```
A
B
B
```